# How to use COUNT, Group by and BETWEEN in the same Query?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm Writing a program with C# to generate reports. Only one table is there which is named "Records" and it contains 3 columns "ID, Date, Name".

What I want to do is count number of ID and group them by the Name,  within a range of dates.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), Name FROM Records GROUP BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;

SELECT * FROM Records WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "';
```

I tried these codes separately. and they are working. First one counts IDs, and the second one shows all the records between Two dates.But I want to combine them into one command.

So I wrote this code.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), Name,Date FROM Records 
GROUP BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "';
```

but it gives me the error " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' ".
Can someone help me with this code? What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I'm not good at SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. `where` clause will come before `group by`.
You may find this link for more info.[Group by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
  ;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT ID, Name,Date FROM Records  
  WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "' )
  SELECT COUNT(ID) AS COUNT_ID, NAME FROM CTE
  GROUP BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

or you can write it as

```
  SELECT COUNT(ID) AS COUNT_ID, NAME FROM (
  SELECT ID, Name,Date FROM Records  
  WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "' ) AS D
  GROUP BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you @DarkRob

I tried your suggestion. and it gives me this error
Column 'Records.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: OMG. That worked perfectly. Thank you so much @DarkRob.
I was struggling with that since last night.

Comment: now I have another problem. that code works but it gives me counts of each day. not the total count of within range.

Comment: That's the perfect one. Thank you so much. @DarkRob

Answer (score 1):

You query format is incorrect. Try this one:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), Name,Date 
FROM Records 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "'
GROUP BY Name, Date 
ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronel Calinisan

I tried your suggestion. and it gives me this error
"Column 'Records.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Just add date in the group by clause. I'll updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you@ Ronel. Now I don't get any error but it gives me output with grouped by date too. which means each day separately. but I want the total count withing the selected date range.

Answer (score 0):

Your query order is wrong.

Try below query, it's working.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), Name, Date FROM Records 
WHERE Date BETWEEN '" +Start_Date+ "' AND '" +End_Date+ "'
GROUP BY Name ORDER BY COUNT(ID) DESC;
```

For learn about  **Order of execution of a Query**, click the link
 https://sqlbolt.com/lesson/select_queries_order_of_execution